# How dynamic change label on basicleafnode popupMenu (xpages)?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

please, show me, how i can dynamical change property Label in basicLeafNode
I use popupMenu, can get it with getComponent("popupMenu1"), i can get getComponent("popupMenu1").treeNodes, but how make next step and get basicLeafNode and his properties?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the label of a basicLeafNode dynamically within a popupMenu hierarchie.

The easiest way is to calculate the label depending on a scope variable like

```
<xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Menu 1">
    <xe:this.label><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        viewScope.dynamicLabel ? viewScope.dynamicLabel : "Default Label"
    }]]></xe:this.label>
</xe:basicLeafNode>
```

Set the `viewScope.dynamicLabel = "Your Changed Label"` when you want to change the label and refresh the popupMenu afterwards.

Comment: Not work - wrote basicLeafNode can't create child item, but idea is great, i bind this label with another method. thank you!

Comment: Good, although scope variable approach works - I tested it before I wrote my answer.